# Adding elements to array but printing wrong values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written this program in C++ that reads an input.txt file containing these numbers 
7
18
5
15
131
11
13
287

The program adds to the array the first value 7, then in the next seven numbers there's random values (such as 0, 4659174, 0, 4778144 etc) and then it prints 7 and 18 and then eight more random numbers and then you can see printed 7, 18, 5 and so on until the last eight numbers are what is actually in the input.txt file.

How can I get it to show only the numbers that are present in the input.txt file instead of all of these random values? Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int myArray[10];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    string number = "";
    char next_letter = '\0';

    while (input.get(next_letter)){
        while (isdigit(next_letter) && !input.eof()){
            number += next_letter;
            input.get(next_letter);
        }

        int val = 0;
        val = atoi(number.c_str());


        myArray[i++] = val;

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            cout << "array contents are: " << myArray[i] << endl;
        }
        number = "";
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PAVANCHANDAKA what would you recommend to fix the issue?

Comment: Put a condition that `nextletter != ' '`in the while loop

Comment: Why second while?

Comment: @PAVANCHANDAKA second while is to look for numbers in the text file until the end of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long myArray[10];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    string number = "";
    const int MAX_LEN = 100;
    char number_str[MAX_LEN];

    while(input.getline(number_str, MAX_LEN - 1, ' ')){
        char* end;
        myArray[i++] = std::strtol(number_str, &end, 10);
    }

    cout << "array contents is: ";
    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        cout << myArray[k] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `getline` does the reading until the `' '` and conversion is done by `strtol`. Please note that it input numbers are `long int` by default.

Comment: I see now, thank you for that! Also the cout output from your code is just the first number of the input.txt which is 7; how would I go about inserting all of the number into the same array?

Comment: My code does display all the numbers on cout. I saw it in my tests. All the numbers are in the array and on the output. Please test again carefully. Please make also sure that your input file does not contain extra symbols like tabulation between the numbers.

Comment: I went into the input text file and put all the numbers on the same line and separated them with spaces and your program worked correctly. However if each number is on a different line (which my text file comes as standard), it only prints the first number

Comment: In general, you should use `getline` with the default separator and parse the input line manually. In this case, the simplest way is using `std::strtok` for parsing.  You can see an explanation and an example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok